# How to convert JavaScript variable to JSON object and insert that JSON object into Mysql using VB.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, vb.net

I want to convert my JavaScript variable into JSON object and insert the JSON Object into MySQL database using VB.Net code.

My Code is like this :

Client-Side :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var Name = $('#txtname').val();
            var Username = $('#txtUsername').val();
            var Password = $('#txtPassword').val();
            if (Name != '' && Username != '' && Password != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/InsertData",
                    data: "{'Name':'" + Name + "','Username':'" + Username + "','Password':'" + Password  + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = data.d;
                        if (obj == 'true') {
                            $('#txtname').val('');
                            $('#txtUsername').val('');
                            $('#txtPassword').val('');
                            $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
               });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please enter all the fields')
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Server Side :

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function InsertData(ByVal username As String, ByVal subj As String, ByVal desc As String) As String
     Dim msg As String = String.Empty
     Using con As New SqlConnection("server=192.168.1.53;charset=utf8;userid=root;password=password;allow user variables=true;database=information")
         Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into userDetails(Name,Username,Password) VALUES(@Name,@Username,@Password)", con)
             con.Open()
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name)
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username)
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password)
             Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
             con.Close()
             If i = 1 Then
                 msg = "true"
             Else
                 msg = "false"
             End If
         End Using
     End Using
     Return msg
 End Function
```

But its showing error.. My JSON variables are not declaring in server-side.I'm new to JSON. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript code is certainly trying to send JSON but your vb.net code is not looking for json. it's looking for standard post data. This sort of data souldn't really be saved as JSON objects. So your vb.net code is right, let's just change the javascript to send a standard post and your VB.NEt code will be able to do the insert without any problems.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/InsertData",
                data: {'Name': Name,'Username': Username, 'Password': Password  },
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = data.d;
                    if (obj == 'true') {
                        $('#txtname').val('');
                        $('#txtUsername').val('');
                        $('#txtPassword').val('');
                        $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
           });
```

Comment: Thank you... But its showing error in my server-side script where adding my variables in sqlcommand as 'Name' is not declared.

Comment: That is of course a completely different question. But that's because you have not defined the parameters properly  ByVal username As String, ByVal subj As String, ByVal desc As String

Comment: Yeah I wrongly defined variables.. But still my JSON data throughs error messsage only..

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: the sucess method in your code is the call back after the asynchronous HTTP request is completed. It will not be call by 'your json method'

Comment: I mean my Json function throughs error message. My json object doesn't calls suucess function. it enters into the following function.

    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }

Comment: so instead of doing alert('error') why do you do alert('result') and why don't you inspect the server log.

Comment: Still I got error message. So I tried to know the error its showing this error "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead." in console.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. You have a call to getPreventDefault() some where else in your code. It's not shown here.

Comment: No i didn't use any code like getPreventDefault().Its showing in the reference file i have added  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js:2:40351"

Comment: that's completely unrelated to this. a google search for getPrevenDefault jquery will give you the solution. I think you might wwant to upgrade that. If it doesn't work, you will have to post a new question. Stackoverflow doesn't like additional issues being discussed in comments.

Comment: From starting itself my error is because of this only. Anyway thank you so much.